# how do I tab in telnet when executing it on remote host by ssh?

Tags: ssh, autocomplete, telnet, connectivity

How can I use `tab` when I use telnet on a remote host by ssh, I have something like:

```
ssh -o StritHopstKeyChecking=no -p port user@hostA telnet hostB; echo "Reconnect?"; while read < /dev/tty; do ssh -o StritHopstKeyChecking=no -p port user@hostA telnet hostB; done
```

which launches the telnet session to `hostB` from `hostA` fine but inside telnet, I can't use `tab` for auto-completion which I can use fine when I manually ssh into `hostA` and then telnet to `hostB` from there. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't used telnet in ages but try using `ssh -t -o ...` in your command.  Does that help?

Comment: @JimL. Yes, that diod help! Excellent, you can move the comment to an answer and i gladly will accept! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some situations, it is helpful to use the `-t` option to tell `ssh` to allocate a pseudo-terminal device for the ssh connection:

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p port user@hostA telnet hostB
```

Another typical example of a command that requires `-t` is remote editing of a file with `vi`, or viewing it with `less`:

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p port user@hostA vi foo.txt
```